# git push no funciona

Tags: git

Instalé Git en una nueva lap, y para terminar de configurarla intente hacer push a un repositorio de ejemplo (esta vacio). Sin embargo, al usar `git push origin master` (desde Git Bash) no pasa nada. Literalmente.

La primera vez que intenté un `commit` se me pidió mi nombre y correo, los cuales ingresé.

Añadí un remote, y solo el correo se me pidió cuando hice el primer commit.

Después, nada. Creí que era normal porque estaba haciendo push a GitHub y solo debía esperar a que me pidiera ingresar mi usuario y contraseña, pero no importó cuanto tiempo pasara, nada ocurrió.

Si uso `git push origin master -verbose` solo me muestra "Pushing to https://...", pero igual se queda sin hacer nada.

En ese estado puedo interactuar con la consola (pulsar Enter o cancelar usando Ctrl+C), por lo que no es que se haya trabado.

Ya he desinstalado y reinstalado, pero nada. En mis otras laptops Git funciona como siempre.

¿Qué podría estar pasando con esta?

**Edit**: Estoy desde Windows 10.

Comment: solo se te pide tú correo y contraseña una vez, asegura te haber colocado el remote o repositorio a donde se hará el `push`

Comment: @Christian Añadí un remote, y solo el correo se me pidió cuando hice el primer commit (se me olvido especificarlo), pero jamas se me abrio la ventana que me pedia ingresara GitHub.

Comment: eso es normal, pues toda esa información se guarda en el sistema. pero con respecto a lo otro, no se que podría estar pasando, tal vez es tu conexión o prueba dar un enter, la consola a veces se *traba*

Comment: SI estas utilizando windows lo que puedes hacer es desactivar el firewall para git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si te sirva, pero a mi me funcionó desinstalar Git y volver a instalarlo, cuando llegues a la parte de "Choosing HTTPS transport Backend", selecciona la opción de "Use the native Windows Secure Channel Library".

Me parece que eso era lo que arreglaba el problema (lo vi por ahí en otro foro). Yo además cambie un par de elecciones como la terminal que iba a usar y cosas por el estilo.

Suerte.

Comment: ¡Funciono! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me paso que mi repositorio estaba muy pesado.

Que hice? Abrir la aplicación GIT GUI, cuando la abrí me mostro la advertencia de que la base de datos estaba muy pesada, me pidio confirmar comprimirla y en cuanto le di clic en comprimir, se lanzo el git push que tenía en la consola.

Si no te sale ese mensaje, ve al menu superior en Repository > Compress Database

Espero les funcione.