# Problema al hacer un push desde Andorid Studio a Github

Tags: android-studio, git, github

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto en Andorid Studio, cuando quiero hacer el push a github se queda pillado en la tarea de Pushing, tengo Git instalado en el ordenador, Android Studio actualizado a la ultima versión, un repositorio creado en Github, y la confuguración de Android Studio hecha para poder hacer los push a ese repositorio, dejo por aqui una imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando hago el push directamente desde Git si que funciona. He probado ya a desinstalar y volver a instalar Git y he intantado cambiar lo que pone en [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463486/git-push-no-funciona) para ver si era eso, pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Agrega mas información , que error se muestra? que sucede al tratar de realizar el push?

Comment: Android Studio verifica que todo funcione bien antes de hacer un commit. Tal vez sea eso lo que está tardando.

Comment: @Jorgesys ese es el problema, que no da ningun codigo de error, y ya he explicado lo que pasa. Lee bien la pregunta

Comment: @Mateo cuanto tarda en verificar más o menos, por que estuve esperando unos 15 minutos y seguía sin funcionar.

Comment: A mí no me tarda más de 1 minuto en un proyecto pequeño que tengo. Podría variar de acuerdo a la computadora pero 15 minutos me parece exagerado. ¿Es el único proyecto de Android con el que te sucede eso? [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17133360/13419694) te podría ayudar.